# Analytical solution for system of nonlinear ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have a system of two nonlinear ODEs with initial conditions. Mathematica's DSolve is unable to produce something. NDSolve gives a plot of two strictly decreasing nonlinear functions from numerically solving this. However I am looking for an analytical solution.

$g'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{1.25-x-h(x)}$

$h'(x)=\frac{h(x)}{1.75-x-g(x)}$

with $g(1)=1$ and $h(1)=1$.

Comment: What makes you think that such a thing should exist? Most ODE solutions can not be expressed in the finite number of named and explored elementary (like exp, sin, roots) or special (like Bessel, hypergeometric) functions.

Comment: When I replace 1.25 and 1.75 by the same number I can write down a solution. And by Picard-Lindelöf (aka Cauchy-Lipschitz) the solution should be unique (by my understanding).

Comment: Yes, that is a general pattern. If you take a symbolically solvable DE and change the coefficients only a little (note that you can introduce parameters with original values 0 or 1 everywhere), then generally you get an equation that does not have symbolic solutions. That does not mean that the solutions do not exist, just that you can not write them down as a finite expression (non-recursive, without limits).